# LinkButton OnClick event not firing

Tags: asp.net, onclick

I've been having this issue in some of my .aspx pages even though the code and everything else is the same as other pages(on which it works fine). I haven't written any new piece of code for these pages and I have tried everything but nothing seems to be working. Can someone please help me on this?

Design Code:

```
 <form runat="server">
       <div class="maincontain">
    <div class="header">
            <ul class="givusacall">
                <li>Call us : + 0000000000 </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="logandreg">
                <li style="width:60px">   <asp:LinkButton ID="login" runat="server" OnClick="login_Click" CausesValidation="false" ForeColor="#f2f2f2"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp; |</li>
                <li style="width:60px">   <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" CausesValidation="false" ForeColor="#f2f2f2"></asp:LinkButton></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Back end Code:

```
 protected void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["USER_ID"] != null)
            {
                login.Text = "LogOut";
                Session.Remove("USER_ID");
                Session.RemoveAll();
                Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
            }

            else if (Session["USER_ID"] == null)
            {
                login.Text = "LogIn";
                Response.Redirect("ulogin.aspx");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Correct me if you have already done this. Did your try to put a break point in the event handler and run the application in debug mode and see if the breakpoint hits when button is clicked?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya No, I didn't. Let me try this out and I'll let you know.

Comment: I'm guessing mikaela01 isn't coming back to let us know :-(